# Python (pygame/tkinter) MP3 Playlist

Tags: python, tkinter

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter import filedialog


#-------------------------------FONCTIONS---------------------------------


def importer_son(event):
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048) 
    pygame.mixer.init()
    Liste_musique.append(file)
    #TEST PRINT
    print(file)
    print (Liste_musique)


def stop_it(event):
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()
    global pause
    pause = 1

def start_it(event):  
    global pause
    if pause == 1:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        pause = 0    
    else:
        try:
            pygame.mixer.music.load(Liste_musique[index])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()
        except:
            showwarning("Error","PAS DE FICHIER")

def close():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    fen1.destroy()

def next_musique(event):
    global index
    index += 1
    try:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(Liste_musique[index])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    except:
        showwarning("Error","PAS DE FICHIER")

def previous_musique(event):
    global index
    index -= 1
    try:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(Liste_musique[index])
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    except:
        showwarning("Error","PAS DE FICHIER")

def reint():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    Liste_musique[:] = []

 #-------------------------------Variables---------------------------------       


Liste_musique = []
global index
index = 0
global pause
pause = 0


#-------------------------------MAIN---------------------------------


fen1 = Tk()
fen1.title("Lecteur Audio en python")

menubar = Menu(fen1)
menu1 = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="Réinitialiser", command=reint)
menu1.add_command(label="Quitter", command=close)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Option", menu=menu1)
fen1.config(menu=menubar)

can1 = Canvas(fen1, height=500, width=500)
can1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

fond_decran = PhotoImage(file="Background.gif")
can1.create_image(0,0, anchor = "nw", image = fond_decran)
can1.image = fond_decran

image_play = PhotoImage(file="Play.gif")
im_play = can1.create_image(50,400, anchor = "nw", image = image_play)
can1.image = image_play


image_stop = PhotoImage(file="stop.gif")
im_stop = can1.create_image(130,400, anchor = "nw", image = image_stop)
can1.image = image_stop


image_prev = PhotoImage(file="prev.gif")
im_prev = can1.create_image(210,400, anchor = "nw", image = image_prev)
can1.image = image_prev


image_next = PhotoImage(file="next.gif")
im_next = can1.create_image(290,400, anchor = "nw", image = image_next)
can1.image = image_next

image_importer = PhotoImage(file="importer.gif")
im_importer = can1.create_image(370,400, anchor = "nw", image = image_importer)
can1.image = image_importer

can1.tag_bind(im_play, '<Button-1>', start_it)
can1.tag_bind(im_stop, '<Button-1>', stop_it)
can1.tag_bind(im_next, '<Button-1>', next_musique)
can1.tag_bind(im_prev, '<Button-1>', previous_musique)
can1.tag_bind(im_importer, '<Button-1>', importer_son)


fen1.mainloop()
fen1.destroy()
```

In the code above I created my mp3 player, it works well but I would like to do a "playlist" : when a music is end go to the next or if there is only one music that it repeats it. To do that I already have a list with all songs (Liste_musique) and an index (index) to see where I am in the list. But I don't see how can I do that. I hope I could have explained well: D

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you essentially want to know if playing the audio is finished or not, right?

Comment: See `pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`, `pygame.mixer.music.queue`, `pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent`, `pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent()` [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html).

Comment: Thanks and sorry for this "stupid" question

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily classify it as such. Also if you have found your solution please add it as answer here.

Comment: I can not validate my own answer, could you answer whereas comment then I can close the topic

Comment: What do you mean you can't validate your own answer? You can select it as _the answer_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nae : See pygame.mixer.music.get_busy(), pygame.mixer.music.queue,
>   pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent, pygame.mixer.music.get_endevent()

Good answer